# Express sum with variable number of terms

Tags: summation

I have the following data for a sum with variable $n$.

For $n=1$, $\text{sum}=p^2+q^2$

For $n=2$, $\text{sum}=3p^2q+q^3$

For $n=3$, $\text{sum}=p^4+6p^2q^2 +q^4$

For $n=4$, $\text{sum}=5p^4q+10p^2q^3+q^5$

and so on.

Is there any way to express the above $\text{sum}$ in terms of $\sum$?
The difficult part is that as n grows the number of terms in sum grows as well and the scalars change. Is there a pattern I am missing??

Comment: Without any context, we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the case $n=2$ is as you have written?

If it were $3p^2q+q^3$, these are the terms in which $p$ has even exponent of the expansion of $(p+q)^n$.

That is

$$\frac{(q+p)^n+(q-p)^n}2$$

Comment: Yea you are right. For n=2 it is3p^2*q +q^3!!

This fraction you wrote applies for all n??

Comment: yeah that is what I was looking for, Thank you very much!